# What is context_today?

Tags: odoo-13

Does anyone know about context_today? I have seen it on sales module. sale.py file.
record.remaining_validity_days = (record.validity_date - fields.Date. **context_today** (record)). days + 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its returns the current date as seen in the clients timezone.

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/odoo/fields.py#L1697